# In C#, can object being locked/unlocked be notified?

Tags: c#, locking, notify

The question is, can I create a class that gets notified when it is locked and unlocked.

```
object myLockObj = new SpecialLockNotifyClass("Bob");
lock (myLockObj)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

And the output you would get is:

```
Trying to lock Bob.
Bob is locked.
Hello.
Bob is unlocked.
```

The idea is two-fold:

1) Set it up so one can see when something is trying to lock (by seeing "trying" message" and waiting indefinitely (by not seeing "locked" message) *everywhere* the lock is used

2) Turn off the outputs and switch back to standard locking when one believes the deadlock problems are solved.

Comment: There is no direct way. lock() statements are converted to `try { Monitor.Enter(); _YOUR_CODE; } finally { Monitor.Exit(); }` . Since this is so, you can centralize the locking of objects via a static class and use not lock() but Monitor.Enter (and Exit), but should be very very careful indeed.: `Synchronizer.Lock(obj);`

Comment: No, but I'd love to hear what the problem is you're trying to solve. It sounds interesting and perhaps there are some other suggestions that can help.

Comment: @OguzOzgul: I was hoping not to have to switch using Monitor.Enter() and .Exit(); I'm not sure I follow your Syncronizer.Lock(obj) hint.

Comment: It is similar to the `MyLock` class in David's answer below.

Comment: @ScottHannen, it's the general problem of finding a deadlock. If such a class were possible, it would be a great way to temporarily turn on a lot of printouts (or whatever you wanted) to track down issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock` is just [syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) for Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit.

You could wrap the Monitor access in a custom Disposable type, and replace your `lock` block with a `using` block.  EG

```
    sealed class MyLock : IDisposable
    {
        private object syncRoot;
        bool lockWasTaken = false;

        public MyLock(object syncRoot)
        {
            this.syncRoot = syncRoot;
            BeforeLock();
            Monitor.Enter(syncRoot, ref lockWasTaken);
        }
        public void Exit()
        {
            if (lockWasTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
                lockWasTaken = false;
                AfterUnlock();
            }
        }

        void BeforeLock()
        {
            //...
        }

        void AfterUnlock()
        {
            //...
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Exit();
        }
    }
```

You could even wrap that in an Extension method and write:

```
using (foo.Lock())
{
}
```

Or if you just want to track the attempts at locking the object you could replace

```
lock(foo) { . . .}
```

with

```
lock(TrackLock(foo))  { . . .}
```

where

```
public static object TrackLock(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Locking {o.ToString()}");
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is simply moving the lock statement to a function an option?

```
object myLockObj = new SpecialLockNotifyClass("Bob");

LockObj(myLockObj);

//
void LockObj(NotifyClassAbstract obj){
   // Notify
   Console.WriteLine($"Ur Object {obj.name} has been locked");

   // Do the lock
   lock (myLockObj)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   }
}
```

You can even have it as a function in the SpecialLockNotifyClass.

```
 myLockObj.Lock();
```

Or you can create an Extention Method

```
public static class LockExtentions {
       public static void Lock(this LockClasss myLockObj){
       // Notify


          Console.WriteLine($"Ur Object {obj.name} has been locked");

          // Do the lock
          lock (myLockObj)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Hello");
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a simple drop in change that will monitor everywhere the lockObj is used.  I agree that I can put in printouts every time I lock or unlock, but if a lock gets used hundreds of different places, this isn't practical.

The issue with the extention is that you lose the scoping of the lock statement.